# Valid reorderings - under new JMM

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, java-memory-model

I just wanted to know whether the below reorderings are valid one or not under new JMM model

```
Original Code: 
     instanceVar1 = value ;//  normal read operation, no volatile
     synchronized(this) {
       instanceVar2 = value2; //normal read operation, no volatile   
     }
     instanceVar3 = value3;  //normal read operation, no volatile
```

The above code can be reordered into the following executions.

```
Case 1:

     synchronized(this) {
       instanceVar2 = value2; //normal read operation, no volatile   
       instanceVar1 = value ;//  normal read operation, no volatile
     }
     instanceVar3 = value3;  //normal read operation, no volatile
```

Another case :

```
Case 2:

  synchronized(this) {
       instanceVar3 = value3;  //normal read operation, no volatile
       instanceVar2 = value2; //normal read operation, no volatile   
       instanceVar1 = value ;//  normal read operation, no volatile
     }
```

Another Case :

```
Case 3: 

    instanceVar3 = value3;  //normal read operation, no volatile
    synchronized(this) {
       instanceVar2 = value2; //normal read operation, no volatile   
       instanceVar1 = value ;//  normal read operation, no volatile
     }
```

Another Case :

```
Case 4: 

    instanceVar3 = value3;  //normal read operation, no volatile
    synchronized(this) {
       instanceVar2 = value2; //normal read operation, no volatile   
     }
    instanceVar1 = value ;//  normal read operation, no volatile
```

Do all the above 4 cases are  valid reordering of original Code under new JMM Model.
I have given all the above reorderings based on my understanding of
http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider how the normal load/stores are reordered with the monitor enter and exits:

Case 1 reorders a normal load/store with a monitor enter which is a valid reordering.

Case 2 reorders a normal load/store with a monitor enter, and a monitor exit followed by a normal load/store, which are valid reorderings.

See a similar example: [Roach Motels and Java Memory Model](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.uk/2007/05/roach-motels-and-java-memory-model.html). This shows that accesses can be moved into a synchronized block but not back out again.

Case 3 and 4 reorders a monitor enter followed by a normal load/store which is not valid.